# Print all node names between two tags in XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML structure:

```
<node0>
  <beforeContainer @id="test">
   <beforeContainer2/>
  </beforeContainer> 
    <container id='1'>
      <node1>
        <node2>
          <text>Test1</text>
        </node2>
      </node1>
    </container>
    <node3>
      <node4>
        <text>Test2</text>
        <node5>
          <container id='2'>
            <node6>
              <button>Click</button>
            </node6>
          </container>
        </node5>
      </node4>
    </node3>
    <text>Test3</text>
     <node7>
       <node8>
         <node9>
           <container id='3'>
             <node10>
               <button>Click2</button>
             </node10>
           </container>
         </node9>
       </node8>
     </node7>
   </node0>
```

I have to extract all the nodes names between consequent `<container>` nodes. The `<container>` nodes are in different level of depth in the tree.

The output should look like this:

```
<container id='1'>
  <node1/>
  <node2/>
  <text/>
  <node3/>
  <node4/>
  <text/>
  <node5/>
</container>
<container id='2'>
  <node6/>
  <button/>
  <text/>
  <node7/>
  <node8/>
  <node9/>
</container>
<container id='3'>
  <node10/><button/>
</container>
```

I tried different x-Path expressions but unsuccessfully since they always have some specific scope(descendant-or-self::node(), following-sibling, etc..)

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 or above?

Comment: Yes. I use XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple grouping problem in XSLT 2 or 3:

```
  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::*" group-starting-with="container">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ." mode="copy"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
      <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Complete sample https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqQ is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::*" group-starting-with="container">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ." mode="copy"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
      <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As for your edit of having elements preceding the first `container` that you don't want to output, change the template doing the grouping to

```
  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::*" group-starting-with="container">
          <xsl:if test="self::container">
              <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ." mode="copy"/>
              </xsl:copy>              
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqQ/1

The way the `for-each-group group-starting-with` works (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-for-each-group) is that if the first item in the group population is not matching the `group-starting-with` pattern it forms a group nevertheless:

> If the group-starting-with attribute is present, then its value must
>   be a pattern.
>
> The items in the population are examined in population order. If an
>   item matches the pattern, or is the first item in the population, then
>   a new group is created and the item becomes its first member.
>   Otherwise, the item is appended to the same group as its preceding
>   item within the population.

This is helpful in many cases but then often requires to use a nested `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose` inside the `xsl:for-each-group` that tests whether we have a "real" group matching the `group-starting-with` pattern or have just collected any items before the first such group.

Comment: Those elements are handled by the `match="*" mode="copy"` template which does the `<xsl:copy/>`, you can change that to `<xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/></xsl:copy>` to copy all their attributes or use a different `select` expression to select only some certain attributes for copying with e.g. `select="@foo, @bar"`.

Comment: I've noticed that the XSLT also prints the element before the first "container" element. Is there a way to skip that ? (I added few "beforeContainer" elements in the example above)

Comment: @PhilipSt, I have edited the answer to address that problem.